# Pivotal quantity example in Bayesian Analysis

Tags: statistics, bayesian

I'm reading the classical Gelman's [Bayesian Data Analysis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1439840954) and on page 54 he states

[image]

I don't know if I understood this correctly, could someone give me a real example of a *pivotal quantity* and why this concept is important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> could someone give me a real example of a pivotal quantity and why this concept is important?

a pivotal quantity, not only in Bayesian Statistics but also in Classical statistics is a function depending both on the data $\mathbf{x}$ and on the parameter ($\theta$) but with a distribution that does not depends on the parameter.

This quantity is very important because you can calculate, for example, confidence intervals, derive hypothesis tests and so on....

---

**Example 1 - Classical Statistics**:

---

Suppose you have the following density

$$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\theta}e^{-x/\theta}$$

considering that this density can be written as

$$\frac{1}{\theta}\psi\left(\frac{x}{\theta}\right)$$

this means that $X$ belongs to the Scale family and as a consequence

$$T=\frac{X}{\theta}$$

is a pivotal quantity.

You can  use $T$ to get a confidence interval because you can calculate

$$a<T<b$$

as $T$ has a distribution that does not depend on the parameter finding as a CI

$$\frac{b}{X}<\theta<\frac{a}{X}$$

---

Sure you know that, if $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, the following quantity

$$Z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$$

is a Standard Gaussian...that is a quantity depending on the parameters, $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ but with a distribution that is always the same $\forall \mu,\sigma^2$ thus it is a pivotal quantity...and sure you know how useful is $Z$ in many statistical calculations

---

**Example 2 - Bayesian**

---

Consider the Statistical model

$$X\sim N(\theta;1)$$

In this case $X-\theta$ is free of $\theta$ thus it suggest use to choose an improper prior that is uniform over the range $(-\infty;+\infty)$

$$h(\theta)=C$$

This is not a proper density but the posterior is! In fact using Bayes' rule we get

$$h(\theta|\mathbf{x})\propto h(\theta)\text{exp}\left\{-\frac{1}{2}\sum_i(x_i-\theta)^2  \right\}=h(\theta)\text{exp}\left\{-\frac{n}{2}(\theta-\overline{x})^2   \right\}$$

Normalizing you get

$$h(\theta|\mathbf{x})=\sqrt{\frac{n}{2\pi}}\text{exp}\left\{   -\frac{n}{2}(\theta-\overline{x})^2 \right\}$$

that is

$$h(\theta|\mathbf{x})\sim N\left(\theta;\frac{1}{n}\right)$$